# how to get a SUM in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do the following, I have a `List` with a class which contains 2 integer id and count

Now I want to do the following linq query:

```
get the sum of the count for each id
```

but there can be items with the same id, so it should be summerized e.g.:

```
id=1, count=12
id=2, count=1
id=1, count=2
```

sould be:

```
id=1 -> sum 14
id=2 -> sum 1
```

how to do this?

Comment: 101 LINQ Samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869#CountConditional

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) the items by `Id` and then [sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) the `Count`s in each group:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                  .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Count) });
```

Comment: what do I have to do if I dont want to use the new, just to sum it up and then get the objects back which I had

Comment: What are you expecting as result? Something like `{Item = {id=1, count=12}, Sum=14}`?

Comment: @Caramiriel Yes, it does look like he wants to create new items of the same type as the original elements, with their counts set to the totals, like: `var result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(g => new HisType {id = g.Key, count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) });`

Answer (score 3):

Try it ,

```
 .GroupBy(x => x.id)
 .Select(n => n.Sum(m => m.count));
```

Answer (score 3):

The following program...

```
struct Item {
    public int Id;
    public int Count;
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var items = new [] {
            new Item { Id = 1, Count = 12 },
            new Item { Id = 2, Count = 1 },
            new Item { Id = 1, Count = 2 }
        };

        var results =
            from item in items
            group item by item.Id
            into g
            select new { Id = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(item => item.Count) };

        foreach (var result in results) {
            Console.Write(result.Id);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
        }

    }

}
```

...prints:

```
1       14
2       1
```