# C# Grouping in LINQ with sum of certain fields

Tags: c#, linq

I have multiple documents which have mostly identical fields. The only two fields which differ are `Price` and `Quantity`. I want to create an `IEnumerable()` which contains the first item that matches each grouping, but with the price and quantity fields replaced with the `sum()` taken from all the other matching items in this grouping.

Ie

```
fieldone   fieldtwo   fieldthree   price   quantity
a1         b1         c1           3       5
a1         b1         c1           13      15
a1         b1         c1           23      25
a2         b2         c2           4       7
a2         b2         c2           14      17
```

Should return:

```
fieldone   fieldtwo   fieldthree   price   quantity
a1         b1         c1           39      45
a2         b2         c2           18      24
```

I've been looking at `GroupBy()` e.g.:

```
var groupedResults = results.GroupBy(a => new { 
    a.Item1.FieldOne, 
    a.Item1.FieldTwo, 
    a.Item2.FieldThree}
)
```

But i dont know how i can use this to get the result i want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get a SUM in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250991/how-to-get-a-sum-in-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this :

```
var result = Db.Entity
       .GroupBy(p=>new {x.fieldone, x.fiedltwo, x.fieldthree})
       .Select(p=> new { 
             fieldone = p.fieldone, 
             fieldtwo = p.fiedltwo, 
             fieldthree = p.fieldthree, 
             price = p.Sum(x=>x.price), 
             quantity = p.Sum(x=>x.quantity)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to project out your group to sum the required fields

```
var groupedResults = results.GroupBy(a => new { 
    a.Item1.FieldOne, 
    a.Item1.FieldTwo, 
    a.Item2.FieldThree}
).Select(g => new {
    g.Key.FieldOne,
    g.Key.FieldTwo,
    g.Key.FieldThree,
    Price = g.Sum(x => x.Price),
    Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
});
```

There is another overload where you can supply a second parameter to `GroupBy` for the result, which saves having a second `Select` chained after the `GroupBy` but personally I prefer this method above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the overload that includes a result selector.

```
var groupedResults = results.GroupBy(a => new 
{ 
    a.Item1.FieldOne, 
    a.Item1.FieldTwo, 
    a.Item2.FieldThree
}, 
(key, items) => new 
{ 
    key.FieldOne,
    key.FieldTwo,
    key.FieldThree,
    Price = items.Sum(a => a.Price), 
    Quantity = items.Sum(a => a.Quantity) 
});
```