# How to Loop through IEnumerable List and if there are any duplicates, sum a value each duplicate has and remove the duplicates in ASP.Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an inventory usage page that is populated with a list of items I've used over the course of a certain period of time (like a month or so). There's a good amount of items that are duplicates and I am trying to basically put a button on the view page (an IEnumerable List) that will populate a pdf with a list of items and their totals. What I can't figure out is how to loop through the list of items and if there is any duplicates, get the "AmtTaken" values and sum them together, then remove the duplicates where it only shows each item once but the "AmtTaken" totals are summed together.
I don't have much code to go off of right now because I'm stuck and am trying to figure out the best way to go about doing this. It's from a database table called "InventoryUsage".

Here is my model:

```
   public partial class InventoryUsage
   {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int ID { get; set; }           
       [Display(Name = "Item Code")]
       public string Item_Code { get; set; }           
       [Display(Name = "Amt Taken")]
       public string Amt_Taken { get; set; }           
       [Display(Name = "Submitted?")]
       public Nullable<bool> Submitted { get; set; }
   }
```

So the duplicates I'm looking for is any with the same Item_Code and then if there is a duplicate, then sum the Amt_Taken values together. I also still want it to list all the items that don't have duplicates. How I have it set currently is with all the items where "Submitted" == false. So with this model, the ID's won't be the same if there is a duplicate so that's another thing that's throwing me off.

Here is my view page:

```
 @model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.InventoryUsage>

     <div class="wrapper">
         <table class="table">
             <tr>
                 <th>
                     Item/RM Code
                 </th>
                 <th>
                     Amt Taken
                 </th>
                 <th>
                     Submitted? (Y/N)
                 </th>
                 <th></th>
             </tr>

             @foreach (var item in Model)
             {
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item_RM_Code)
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amt_Taken)
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @if (item.Submitted_ == true)
                         {
                             <label class="lbl-yes">Yes</label>
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             <label class="lbl-no">No</label>
                         }
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.ActionLink("Generate List", "GetTotals", new { not sure what to put here yet }) |
                         @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                         @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             }
         </table>
     </div>
```

And for my controller, is where I don't have much code yet as I am totally stumped.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var usage = from u in db.InventoryUsage
                    select u;

        return View(usage.Where(u => u.Submitted_ == false).ToList());
    }


    public ActionResult GetTotals()
    {
        var list = db.InventoryUsage.Where(x => x.Submitted == false).ToList();

        //Stuck on this part//

    }
```

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) Why is `Amt_Taken` a string and not a numeric type like `decimal`? How do you sum the string values? 2) Do [LINQ Remove duplicates and result item to have sum of quantities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50449204) and/or [how to get a SUM in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16250991) answer your question?

Comment: @dbc when I first made the database table, I formatted it wrong. I should have added a "unit of measure" column, but decided to just keep it a text column so I could put (as an example: "10 lbs" or "10 gal" instead of having to do 2 different fields. It wasn't until I started wanting to try to do this list function that I realized I messed up and can't do that for this to work. So I am gonna have to add that new column for unit of measure and change the AmtTaken to numerical. But either way, as long as there is just a numerical value, it should still sum it right?

Comment: As long as you have some way to get a numerical value for each `InventoryUsage`, I believe you should be able to use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251043/3744182) by dtb to [how to get a SUM in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16250991/3744182) to get your sum: `db.InventoryUsage.GroupBy(x => x.Item_Code).Select(g => new { Item_Code = g.Key, Amt_Taken= g.Sum(x => GetValue(x.Amt_Taken)) })`.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Also, those examples are confusing me and don't see how I can make that apply to my example. They are using a generic list and matching them by ID whereas I cannot match mine by the ID.

Comment: See also: [Best way to store units in database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18539)

Comment: @KipM. - You wrote *So the duplicates I'm looking for is any with the same Item_Code* so just replace `x => x.Id` with `x => x.Item_Code`.

Comment: Are you sure all the inventory items with the same `Item_Code` will have the same units?  Could one item be "1 gm" while another is "1 kg" (i.e. 1000 grams)?

Comment: it will just be lbs, gallons, or just the number (no units). So as long as it calculates the number, it should still be ok. I will try these examples and see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GroupBy` and sum the results:

```
IEnumerable<InventoryUsage> usages = ...;

var aggregatedUsages = usages.GroupBy( iu => iu.Item_Code )
    .Select( g => new
    {
        Item_Code = g.Key,
        Amt_Taken = g.Select( iu => Convert.ToInt32( iu.Amt_Taken ) )
            .Sum();
    } );
```

You didn't specify on how to deal with mismatches in `Submitted` values for the same `Item_Code`.  You can make that part of the `GroupBy` key if you want the amounts summed by item code & submitted/not submitted values:

```
usages.GroupBy( iu => new { iu.Item_Code, iu.Submitted } )
```

Then project those properties:

```
.Select( g => new
{
    Item_Code = g.Key.Item_Code,
    Submitted = g.Key.Submitted,
    Amt_Taken = ...,
} )
```

Comment: thanks @Moho, I will give this a try and let you know! One question though, what is the g.Key value? I don't get where that came from?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32( iu.Amt_Taken )` -- this uses localized parsing.  Since the locale used will be that of the server rather than the client, it might not be appropriate.  Querent really should reconsider their DB design to avoid this sort of pitfall.

Comment: @KipM. - it's [`IGrouping<TKey,TElement>.Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2.key).

Comment: @KipM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0

Comment: When doing the example above, I keep getting an invalid input data type when doing the "Convert.ToInt32" so I went back and changed the data type to decimal since some of my values will be decimal amounts. After doing that, now it keeps saying "System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,KTC_QC1.Models.InventoryUsage_QC], but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[KTC_QC1.Models.InventoryUsage_QC]'."

Comment: I also tried the way @dbc recommended where instead of '.Sum()', I did 'db.InventoryUsage.GroupBy(x => x.Item_Code).Select(g => new { Item_Code = g.Key, Amt_Taken= g.Sum(x => x.Amt_Taken)})' and I got the same error message I mentioned above.

Comment: @KipM. what dictionary?

Comment: @KipM. -- *After doing that, now it keeps saying "System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type...* Then you should probably ask a second question, because the format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).  Be sure to include a [mcve].  Or you could [edit] your original question, but you're more likely to get useful help here if you break your problem down in as many small, atomic questions as possible.

Comment: @dbc, well I did only ask one question. I'm trying to figure out how to generate a list that loops through all the records and if there are duplicate values, then get those values and sum them together. After trying the suggestion you recommended I was simply just sharing that I got an error message. I don't have alot of experience with grouping and generating lists, the ones I've done in the past are much simpler and straight forward. So I apologize I'm not as knowledgeable about all the functions mentioned. I'm just stuck on this and am desperate to figure out how to do it.

Comment: so that's why I broke down and posted my question because I had pretty much gotten as far as I was most likely going to get on my own at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this to work. @dbc and @Moho, thank you both very much! You pointed me in the right direction and after looking into more stuff about grouping methods, I ended up just making a few minor tweaks to your all's suggestions. For some reason, it wasn't letting me do this with my database entity model since it uses a generic list, so I created another model class called UsageTotalsModel and just added the relevant fields from the InventoryUsage Model. I'm guessing since this isn't a database entity model, it can use a generic list that this function uses. Here is my new model I added:

```
  public class UsageTotalsModel
  {
      public UsageTotalsModel() { }


      public string Item_Code { get; set; }
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.###}")]
      public Nullable<decimal> Amt_Taken { get; set; }
      public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }       
      public Nullable<bool> Submitted { get; set; }
      public InventoryUsage Usage { set; get; }
  }
```

So in my controller, I just pulled the data from InventoryUsage and added it to the UsageTotalsModel. This fixed the error message I kept getting.

```
    public ActionResult GetTotals()
    {
        var usage = from u in db.InventoryUsage
                    where u.Submitted == false
                    group u by u.Item_Code into g
                    orderby g.Key
                    select new UsageTotalsModel() { Item_Code = g.Key, Amt_Taken = g.Sum(u => u.Amt_Taken) };
                 
        var result = usage.ToList();
        return new ViewAsPdf("GetTotals", result) { PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait };
    }
```

Now the only problem I have is that the items with decimal points, are automatically rounding to the nearest tenth so on some of the amounts where it is 0.02 lbs it is showing up as 0. But that's a different question, if I get stuck on it, I'll post another question for that issue, but I should be able to figure it out. Anyways, thanks for the help on this! I would not have ever thought to do the group by and select method. The stuff I found online seemed confusing and wasn't sure if it applied to me, but thanks to you all, you made it make sense!